# Display $PATH as a list

Tags: linux, bash

how can I display all the paths from $PATH like this?

```
Path 1: usr/bin
Path 2: /bin
... and so on.
```

I'm very new to this so I have no idea what to do with grep and how to display it like this. Thx in advance

Comment: Why would you think `grep` is useful for this? It's for printing matching lines, not for reformatting data.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not quite sure why you want this? `tr` can translate character:

```
$ echo "$PATH" | tr ':' $'\n'
/usr/bin
/bin
...
```

`tr` will translate SET1 (`:`) to SET2 (newlines)

Alternative you can use AWK to format it a little nicer:

```
$ awk '{ print "Path: "NR, $0 }' RS=: <<< "$PATH"
Path 1: /usr/bin
Path 2: /bin
...
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work with empty PATH components, which mean `.`.

Comment: @Jens Care to elaborate? You mean `.` should be expanded to cwd? :-)

Comment: The shell treats empty PATH components in `:/bin`, `/bin:` or `/usr/bin::/bin` as if they were `.`. It's been like that forever and is likely documented in your shell manual (it's in my sh(1) man page on FreeBSD). General wisdom of today is that it is a bad feature (just like having `.` anywhere) and should not be used because of the security implications.

Answer (score 2):

In a shell script you could do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=':' read -ra ITEMS <<< "$PATH"
for i in "${ITEMS[@]}"; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

This will print out each individual PATH setting in the list on a separate line.

If you want to do something else with it you just change the command(s) inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Little **awkish** solution :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"}{printf "Path %d: %s\n",++i,$0}' <<<"$PATH"
```

---

**Output**

```
Path 1: /home/ssam/bin
Path 2: /usr/local/sbin
Path 3: /usr/local/bin
Path 4: /usr/sbin
Path 5: /usr/bin
Path 6: /sbin
Path 7: /bin
Path 8: /usr/games
Path 9: /usr/local/games
Path 10: /dingo/mingo
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Herestrings or `<<<` is supported only by a [[ few ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) shells.
2. My GNU bash version is 4.3.11 where `<<<` is supported.

Comment: is this not the same like in the answer from andlrc?

Comment: @incBrain : Well my mistake pal :(, I never saw the the awk part  the other answer.  There is a difference too, I use a counter `i` where the the other uses a the record number `NR`.

Comment: ah sry, I didn't notice that difference. And you also did a nice job in the **Notes** section ))

Comment: @incBrain : The other answer uses awk inbuilt variable, so i think is superior to mine.I was tempted to put the notes  because `<<<` makes the script less portable. For instance  it will not work in older `dash` shells as mentioned in this [\[ document \]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism). Strange enough it works in my version of `dash` which is quite new.

Comment: @sjsam What version of dash you got? Mine is `0.5.8-1` installed from pacman. I'm pretty sure `<<<` is not and will never be part of dash.

Comment: @andlrc : Consider the last part of my previous comment as a mistake. You're right, dash gives me `Syntax error: redirection unexpected
` error.

Comment: @andlrc : You may be interested in what lead me to that wrong conclusion. Check [\[ this \]](http://pastebin.com/raw/42pBsy0W) if time permits ;)

Comment: I see. You are not the first to run into this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` like this,

```
$ awk -F\: '{
  for (i = 0; ++i <= NF;)
    print "Path", i,":", $i
  }' <<<$PATH
Path 1 : /usr/local/sbin
Path 2 : /usr/local/bin
Path 3 : /usr/sbin
Path 4 : /usr/bin
Path 5 : /sbin
Path 6 : /bin
Path 7 : /usr/games
Path 8 : /usr/local/games
Path 9 : /snap/bin
```

If you want to use `PYTHON` you can try like this,

```
$ python -c "import os; print '\n'.join(os.environ['PATH'].split(':'))"
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

Comment: Some people like doing things the hard way ;)